# PL/SQL: Cómo contar frecuencia de valores en una columna

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio que no sé por dónde encararlo. Agradecería vuestra ayuda!

Tengo la tabla de pizzas con sus ingredientes, la descripción de los ingredientes y la tabla de ordenes:

> [image: Ingredientes]

> [image: Ordenes]

> [image: Pizzas]

El ejercicio me pide imprimir una nueva pizza que tenga los 5 ingredientes más utilizados en los últimos 6 meses. Cómo hago ese contador de cada uno de los ingredientes utilizados dentro de un array? La verdad es que me mató! Gracias!

Les dejo el código para insertar datos en un mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE sys.orders(
order_id int NOT NULL,
customer_id int NULL,
pizza_id int NULL,
exclusions varchar(4) NULL,
extras varchar(4) NULL,
order_time datetime NULL);

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(1, 101, 1, N'', N'', CAST(N'2021-02-01T18:05:02.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(2, 101, 1, N'', N'', CAST(N'2021-02-01T19:00:52.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(3, 102, 1, N'', N'', CAST(N'2021-03-02T23:51:23.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(3, 102, 2, N'', NULL, CAST(N'2021-03-02T23:51:23.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(4, 103, 1, N'4', N'', CAST(N'2021-05-04T13:23:46.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(4, 103, 2, N'4', N'', CAST(N'2021-05-04T13:23:46.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(5, 104, 1, N'null', N'1', CAST(N'2021-06-08T21:00:29.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(6, 101, 2, N'null', N'null', CAST(N'2021-06-08T21:03:13.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(7, 105, 2, N'null', N'1', CAST(N'2021-06-08T21:20:29.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(8, 102, 1, N'null', N'null', CAST(N'2021-07-09T23:54:33.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(9, 103, 1, N'4', N'1, 5', CAST(N'2021-08-10T11:22:59.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(10, 104, 1, N'null', N'null', CAST(N'2021-09-11T18:34:49.000' AS DateTime));

INSERT sys.orders (order_id, customer_id, pizza_id, exclusions, extras, order_time) VALUES
(11, 115, 3, NULL, N'8', CAST(N'2021-09-11T19:45:29.000' AS DateTime)) ;



CREATE TABLE sys.pizza(
id int NOT NULL,
name varchar(50) NULL,
ingredients varchar(50) NULL);

INSERT sys.pizza (id, name, ingredients) VALUES (1, N'Carnivore', N'1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10');

INSERT sys.pizza (id, name, ingredients) VALUES (2, N'Vegetarian', N'4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12');

INSERT sys.pizza (id, name, ingredients) VALUES (3, N'Prosciutto e sql', N'11, 12, 13, 6') ;



CREATE TABLE sys.ingredients(
id int NOT NULL,
name varchar(40) NULL);

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (1, N'Bacon');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (2, N'BBQ Sauce');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (3, N'Beef');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (4, N'Cheese');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (5, N'Chicken');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (6, N'Mushrooms');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (7, N'Onions');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (8, N'Pepperoni') ;

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (9, N'Peppers');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (10, N'Salami');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (11, N'Tomatoes');

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (12, N'Tomato Sauce') ;

INSERT sys.ingredients (id, name) VALUES (13, N'Prosciutto') ;
```

Comment: Vale es mysql lo acabo de comprobar y eso del contador puede hacerse declarando una variable y en un bucle while que se incremente el valor; y no te hace falta ningun array esto se puede hacer mediante cursores

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez el PL-SQL lo utilizaría para normalizar la tabla en la que defines los ingredientes de cada pizza. Si esta modificación, por lo corta que es, la puedes realizar manualmente, sería así:

```
ALTER TABLE ingredients ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
ALTER TABLE pizza ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);

CREATE TABLE form(
  id_form int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_pizza int,
  id_ingredient int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_pizza) REFERENCES pizza(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_ingredient) REFERENCES ingredients(id),
  UNIQUE(id_pizza,id_ingredient)
  );

INSERT INTO form (id_pizza, id_ingredient) VALUES
  (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,8),(1,10),
  (2,4),(2,6),(2,7),(2,9),(2,11),(2,12),
  (3,11),(3,12),(3,13),(3,6);
```

Una vez has normalizado los datos, ya podrías resolverlo con una simple consulta, no necesitas programar nada:

```
SELECT id_ingredient,name,COUNT(*) freq
  FROM orders
  JOIN form ON pizza_id=id_pizza
  JOIN ingredients ON id_ingredient=ingredients.id
  WHERE order_time>NOW()-INTERVAL 6 MONTH
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY freq DESC
  LIMIT 5;
```

Si tuvieras muchos más ingredientes, yo automatizaría el `INSERT` desde una función. Algo así:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inserta_ingredientes(v_id_pizza int,v_ingredientes varchar(127))
RETURNS int
BEGIN
  DECLARE i int;
  WHILE LOCATE(',',v_ingredientes) DO
    set i=SUBSTR(v_ingredientes,1,LOCATE(',',v_ingredientes)-1);
    INSERT INTO form (id_pizza, id_ingredient) VALUES (v_id_pizza,i);
    set v_ingredientes=SUBSTR(v_ingredientes,LOCATE(',',v_ingredientes)+1);
  end WHILE;
  INSERT INTO form (id_pizza, id_ingredient) VALUES (v_id_pizza,v_ingredientes);
  return v_id_pizza;
END;
```

Y realizaría el volcado de datos desde la tabla `pizza`, así evito usar un cursor, que es mucho más lento:

```
SELECT *,inserta_ingredientes(id,ingredients) FROM pizza;
```

Y, a partir de ese momento, dejaría de guardar los datos sin normalizar :)

Comment: gracias por responder! Si, creo que esa seria una variante. Pero supongamos que hay muchos más datos, y no podes normalizar, cuál sería la solución más adecuada? Gracias!

Comment: buen día! Me quedó clarísimo, muchas gracias! Entonces si, hay que normalizar si o si. Saludos!

Comment: Mejor hacerlo bien de una vez que andar con parches, desde luego... :) Ya has visto que normalizando todo resulta mucho más sencillo

Comment: Si claro David! Y ya que estoy te pregunto por el otro enunciado que me pide el ejercicio:
- Generar en orden alfabético separado por comas una lista de ingredientes por cada pizza agregando 2x delante de cada ingrediente que requiere un extra en la pizza. Por ejemplo:
Para order_id = 5 would sería: "2xBacon, BBQ Sauce, Beef, Cheese, Chicken, Mushrooms,
Pepperoni, Salami". Acá vos como lo encararías?

Comment: Busca algo de información sobre `GROUP_CONCAT`, intenta algo, si no te sale crea una nueva pregunta y elimina esta respuesta... Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta anterior, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)